# Xamarin.Forms Portable + Mono.Data.Sqlite.Portable

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms

Good day to everyone,
I'm building an application in Xamarin.Forms Portable for iOS,Android,Windows Universal(10) .

I'm trying to use the Mono.Data.Sqlite.Portable, but I'm not able to create or connect to a local database, I've tried many solutions to fix the problem,  but until now I dint find the solution..

The error is trow at "connection.open();"

The Code is :

```
  var config = DependencyService.Get<DB.IConfig>();
        var cnn =  config.DirectoryDB;


        using (var connection = new SqliteConnection("" +
            new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                DataSource = "URI=file::memory:",
                Version=3,

            }))
        {
            //connection.ChangeDatabase("hello.db");

            connection.Open();
            using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var insertCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
                insertCommand.Transaction = transaction;
                insertCommand.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE TESTE(teste as varchar(10))";
                insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                transaction.Commit();
            }                
        }
```

on the "DataSource" I've a local path, and other paths.
(Ex:. C:\Users\MyMachineName\AppData\Local\Packages\f736c883-f105-4d30-a719-4bf328872f5e_nh7s0b45jarrj\LocalState\hello.db)

The error is :

> An exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The method or operation is not implemented.

[ImageError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhvaE.png)

[Connection Extra Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6aN1.png)

The last picture, it may give more information....

Thank you all in advance :)

Comment: have you read the docs on using SQLite with XF?  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/databases/

Comment: Yes i've ready it, and i've already implemented the PCL version that they show, but that version is ORM.
I'm trying to use the OleDB

Comment: that project hasn't been updated in a year, and the project site is 404 - I'm not sure that I would rely on it

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution,I hope it helps the people that may be looking for the same as I.

Just go to Nuget - And download the Portable.Data.Sqlite that relies on SQLitePCL (Latest version) .
This package (Portable.Data.Sqlite) it will use the connection and will create SqliteDataReader and other property's that we are used to use .

This will work on Visual Studio 2015 and the project must be in framework 4.51 +=

*----Error Tips----*

if you encounter this error : Cant use Temporary Database or Path, just download Sqlite.dll and place on the project BIN folder and System32/ SysWoW64 .